I am still kind of unfamiliar with Flask, and I am completely stuck on this error. "user table not found" in Insomnia / Postman
This is the code creating the user model in my models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


"""
class User:
    id:integer
    username:string
    email:string
    password:string
"""

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(25),nullable=False,unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.Text(),nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User {self.username}>"
    
    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

This is the code for the Sign Up model
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_restx import Resource, Namespace, fields
from models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_jwt_extended import (JWTManager, create_access_token, create_refresh_token, jwt_required, get_jwt_identity)


auth_ns=Namespace('auth', description='Authentication related operations')


signup_model=auth_ns.model(
    'SignUp',
    {
        "username": fields.String(),
        "email": fields.String(),
        "password": fields.String()   
    }
)


@auth_ns.route('/signup')
class SignUp(Resource):
    @auth_ns.expect(signup_model, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        data=request.get_json()
        
        username=data.get('username')
        
        db_user=User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if db_user is not None:
            message_error='Username already exists'
            return message_error, 400
        
        new_user=User(
            username=data.get('username'),
            email=data.get('email'),
            password=generate_password_hash(data.get('password'))
        )
        
        new_user.save()


        return make_response(jsonify({"message": "User created successfully"}),201)


I can run the localhost just fine as there doesn't seem to be errors in my code, and I can even run this test below and it will give me a signup response and I can use my login model and get an access and refresh token
class APITestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(TestConfig)
        self.client = self.app.test_client(self)

        with self.app.app_context():
            # db.init_app(self.app)

            db.create_all()

    def test_signup(self):
        signup_response = self.client.post(
            '/auth/signup',
            json={
                "username": "testuser",
                "email": "test@email.com",
                "password": "password"
            }
        )

        status_code = signup_response.status_code

        self.assertEqual(status_code, 201)
        
    def tearDown(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            db.session.remove()
            db.drop_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()   

The issue is when I try to send a Signup (POST) through Insomnia or Postman connecting to localhost:5000, it is telling me "user table not found".
This was working previously and I'm 95% sure there is nothing relevant I changed in my code when it suddenly stopped working.
{
    "username":"testman",
    "email":"test@gmail.com",
    "password":"password"
}

When it was working, I would send in a signup object and get:
{'message': 'User created successfully'}

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling things like SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy, as well as running VS Code and Insomnia as administrator

What does your connection URL look like?

localhost:5000/auth/signup

Sorry, I meant your SQLAlchemy connection URL. It looks something like mysql+pymysql://…

Where would that be at, is that in Insomnia or VS Code?

In VSCode. It will look similar to the example in the tutorial: app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///project.db"

This is what is in my config.py file and what is being ran when I run the run.py file
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="sqlite:///dev.db"
    DEBUG=True
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO=True```

Okay, now search your project tree (including subfolders) for files named "dev.db" and see if you find more than one,

There is only one dev.db file, it is in the instance folder and it is empty

If the database is empty then you need to create the tables.

That seems to have fixed it! I had those app.context createapp lines of code in my test_api.py, which is why my tests were working but it wasn't in my main.py for some reason, that's what was throwing me off
